# I have older version of python but i need newer version how to install new version without removing older?

Tags: python, cmd

I have older version of python but i need newer version how to install new version without removing older. And one thing is making me so confused. How can i run them in command line. If i use pip it runs in 3.6 version. But it must run the code in 3.9 version.

Comment: Are you on windows? (you should probably mention it in your question)

Comment: use pyenv on windows if you need multiple versions. I also use it on my Mac because why not

Comment: You need to use virtual environment. You can have multiple different version of Python on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 or more python versions on you machine. All you have to do when you want to specify which version to use is to do python I.e

```
python3.x -m venv <name>
```

With that, you can specify your desire python version.